# Are non Turing-complete languages considered programming languages at all?

Tags: programming-languages, language-features, turing-completeness

Reading a recent question: [Is it actually possible to have a 'useful' programming language that isn't Turing complete?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/172879/is-it-actually-possible-to-have-a-useful-programming-language-that-isnt-turin), I've come to wonder whether non Turing-complete programming languages are considered programming languages at all.

Since Turing-completeness means a language has to have variables to store values as well as control structures ( for, while )... Is a language that lacks these features considered a programming language ?

Comment: Define "real programming language".

Comment: @YannisRizos I deleted the phrase "real programming language" to make the question better.

Comment: Ok then, define "programming language" ;) Is Latex a programming language? (see: http://en.literateprograms.org/Turing_machine_simulator_(LaTeX))

Comment: @YannisRizos Can you write programs in LaTeX ?

Comment: Did you follow the link? Here's another one: http://www.haskell.org/wikiupload/8/85/TMR-Issue13.pdf

Comment: @YannisRizos I'm reading it. If the answers to this question correct a misconception of mine, then its purpose will be served.

Comment: The definition of programming language is rather vague. Tex may be Turing-complete, but is it a programming language? If we go by mikera's definition, yes it is. But _most_ people would call Tex a typesetting system...

Comment: Related: [Measure of power other than Turing completeness](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/812/measure-of-power-other-than-turing-completeness?rq=1)

Comment: I'd like to note that "All Turing-complete languages need to have variables control structures" does not imply "Non-Turing-complete languages don't have those features". There are languages that aren't Turing complete and that still have variables, for-loops and while-loops. Also it's not true that you need those features to be Turing-complete. There are languages that don't have a concept of variables and are still Turing-complete. And of course there are languages that don't have imperative looping statements and instead use recursion to iterate. Still Turing-complete.

Comment: I would say that there are "control structures" of different kinds. Immediate differences would be between "looping constructs" (for, while, until, ...) and branching constructs (if, switch, cond, ...). Of course, most looping constructs are "branch and transfer of control" under the hood.

Comment: @Vatine: Lambda Calculus and Combinator Calculus have neither looping constructs nor branching constructs, yet they are Turing-complete. Lambda Calculus only has function abstraction and function application. It doesn't even have named recursion!

Comment: @JörgWMittag Yes, but it also has "lazy semantics", and that (combined with and/or) is enough to get you a choice. Looping constructs then come trivially with the help of the Y-combinator.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Whether or not you want to call them "programming languages" depends on your definition, but it my view the answer is **yes**: you can regard a non-turing complete language as a programming langauge.

Consider the following definition (from Wikipedia):

> A programming language is an artificial language designed to
>   communicate instructions to a machine, particularly a computer.
>   Programming languages can be used to create programs that control the
>   behavior of a machine and/or to express algorithms precisely.

A non-turing complete DSL could easily meet all of these requirements. You can't necessarily express *all* algorithms (this would require Turing completeness), but you could express enough algorithms to be useful in the given domain.

Also as a slightly pedantic but philosophically important point - modern computers are actually finite state machines so are *not* strictly turing complete (Turing completeness actually requires infinite memory....). So in some sense, no language as currently implemented on a modern computer is Turing complete.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph. It's good to remember this from time to time.

Comment: You have to distinguish between the *language* and its *implementation*. It is not physically possible to have Turing-completeness in the real world because (as far as we know) the universe is finite. However, you can still have a language that is Turing-complete, you just cannot faithfully implement it. But, for example, C is not even theoretically Turing-complete: the language specification guarantees that you can take the address of an arbitrary piece of memory, and it guarantees that you can store this address in a pointer of finite size. Yet, C is considered a programming language.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: Very good point. Do you know if there is a formal way to distinguish between languages that we consider intuitively as Turing complete (like C or Lisp), and those that we don't?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a language which can express some algorithm but not all?

Comment: For example, you cannot calculate the Ackermann function in a programming language where you have no recursion and where you can only have loops where the maximum number of iterations must be calculated before the loop starts.

Comment: There's an example of a non Turing-complete language in the bitcoin transaction system.  Each coin has an associated program associated with it which defines who can spend it (such as "the holder of my private key can spend me").  The language is intentionally not Turing complete so that miners, who must execute these scripts while mining, have a guarantee that the script can run in bounded time.